# can i close a specific tab through cypress api?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm using cypress to test my chrome extension, when i'm loading the extension into the browser it's open a url automatically, can i close the tab through cypress api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cypress docs mention this in the trade-off section:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Permanent-trade-offs-1

Permanent trade-offs:

- Cypress is not a general purpose automation tool.
- Cypress commands run inside of a browser.
- **There will never be support for multiple browser tabs.**
- You cannot use Cypress to drive two browsers at the same time.
- Each test is bound to a single origin.

Comment: Thanks, found it 30 seconds after the post :)